# is it possible to use the str.extract to extract all rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data frame.

```
    ID
0   A01G
1   A43B
2   A45C
3   A61B
4   B01J
5   B08B
```

and I have tried to extract them with this code

```
df.iloc[0, 1:2].str.extractall('(.)(.{2})(.*)')
```

and got this result

```
    0   1   2

ID  A   01  G
```

but I would like to extract all rows, then I edit the code to this

```
df.iloc[:, 1:2].str.extract('(.)(.{2})(.*)')
```

to see all rows be extracted as my expected results

```
        0   1   2

ID      A   01  G
        A   43  B
        A   45  C
        A   61  B
        B   01  J
        B   08  B
```

but this `df.iloc[:, 1:2].str.extract('(.)(.{2})(.*)')` is not working and also executed the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-ef9138002e22> in <module>()
----> 1 df_new.iloc[:, 1:2].str.extractall('(.)(.{2})(.*)')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4370             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4371                 return self[name]
-> 4372             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4373 
   4374     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need select by `1` only for return `Series` from second column, because [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is not implemented for `DataFrame`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1].str.extract('(.)(.{2})(.*)')
```

Or select by column name for Series:

```
df['ID'].str.extract('(.)(.{2})(.*)')
```

If use:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:2]
```

it return one column DataFrame, so error raise.

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
   col    ID
0   10  A01G
1   10  A43B
2   10  A45C
3   10  A61B
4   10  B01J
5   10  B08B

print (df.iloc[:, 1])
0    A01G
1    A43B
2    A45C
3    A61B
4    B01J
5    B08B
Name: ID, dtype: object

print (type(df.iloc[:, 1]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (df.iloc[:, 1:2])
     ID
0  A01G
1  A43B
2  A45C
3  A61B
4  B01J
5  B08B

print (type(df.iloc[:, 1:2]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Your first code working nice, because one element Series is returned:

```
print (df.iloc[0, 1:2])
ID    A01G
Name: 0, dtype: object

print (type(df.iloc[0, 1:2]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```